# prettyPhoto not working after including previous detached content

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I've stumbled into a problem and can't workout a way to make it work.

I'm doing this portfolio page and I'm doing the navigation via jQuery.

All images are anchored with the correct link and rel="prettyPhoto".

At the start of the page, it detaches every anchor and append it again. In this first page, prettyPhoto works fine. The problem is when I navigate to another page clicking next or previous and it stop working.

What's weird is that in the first page it works and the other ones doesn't but I use the same progs to detach and append it back.

Here is the link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SNJYcuVh

Some variables are in portuguese. I hope it doesn't mess you up.

ps.: I tried calling again jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'dark_square', autoplay: false, social_tools:''}); after clicking next or previous but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `live` to `on` and change listener to `body` as shown below:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", "a[rel^='prettyPhoto']", function() {
    jQuery.prettyPhoto.open(jQuery(this).attr("href"),"","");
    return false;
})
```

;

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I've rushed with my conclusion. So I've deleted my previous answer because it gave me another problem.

After clicking on Next or Previous, prettyPhoto opens only the same image and not the one that is on the current anchor tag.

I'm really lost here. I don't even know where to go.
Maybe I'll remake all programing for this area.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe the fadeOut and fadeIn are the vilains here?

Because I have some 'Filter Buttons' and with them it work flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Find a way out.

It's was just simple.

I called prettyPhoto init function again after each interaction of the end-user to the portfolio page and it worked.

Thanks for all help.